# Why SQLite stores dates in 13-digits format? And why can't IDE read this format properly? Java

Tags: java, date, sqlite, unix-timestamp

In SQLite I use integer to store dates. When I save any date (which I do by converting `LocalDate` to `java.sql.Date`) it shows as 13-digit integer.

just like this

[image: just like this]

According to [sqlite docs](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) dates should be a unix timestamp which is 10-digit integer. I assume because of dates being stored in 13-digit format Intellij Idea IDE doesn't recognize them as proper dates and I can't edit them with built-in editor.

when I click on a date to change it IDE resets the value

[image: when I click on a date to change it IDE resets the value]

Comment: It's *epoch time*. Specifically, the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 at midnight universal coordinated time.

Comment: Seconds snce the epoch are 10 digits, milliseconds since the epoch are 13 digits. And yes, this way of representing points on the time line comes from Unix.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch now i get why it's 13-digits, thanks. I'm confused though why IDEs and sqlite gui editors recognize dates so poorly

Comment: A number is not a date. Regardless of which IDE you are talking about: how should it know that a specific number should be treated as an epoch value?

Comment: This is not one of [SQLite's supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime), it's just what Java uses by default.

Comment: An aside, doesn’t a modern SQLite JDBC driver support saving a `LocalDate` directly to the database? Going through `java.sql.Date` seems outmoded to me, but this is not my home field.